# how to get the value of each screen‘s camera via python?

Tags: python, camera

[image: C.space]

there are two screens in one blender file，each screen use local camera，i need the camera.name for other code,  the code "Cam= bpy.context.scene.camera " just get the result of active camera. i need the the result of local camera in running  each screens(ps:running in left screen get the result "0R",running in right screen get the result "0F"). how to write the code?"Cam= bpy.context.scene.local_camera"?
following is my full code.want to use local camera name of each screen to select gp layer,how to modify these code?

```
cam=local_camera
if ('0F' in cam.name):i=1
if ('0R' in cam.name):i=0    
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
objectToSelect = bpy.data.objects["Annotations"]
objectToSelect.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = objectToSelect
bpy.ops.gpencil.layer_active(layer=i)
```

Comment: i modify my question, so please tell me how to get the local camera of each screens? not the list of all camera names, just one everytime running. thank you.

Comment: If running in the context of a 3d view,  `cam = context.space_data.camera`

Comment: thanks for answer，i have done on basis of accepted answer, is:   C = bpy.context
for area in C.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        cam=C.area.spaces.active.camera

Comment: Should be: `cam = area.spaces.active.camera`, have a look at the print call @leeblues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all [areas of type `'VIEW_3D'`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html?highlight=area#bpy.types.Area.type) and use [`SpaceView3D.camera`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html?highlight=camera#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.camera) attribute on the [active space](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AreaSpaces.html#bpy.types.AreaSpaces.active):

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

# Iterate through all areas
for area in C.screen.areas:
    # Determine whether the area is of type VIEW_3D
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        # Get the active space (SpaceView3D) print the actual attribute
        print ("Object reference:", area.spaces.active.camera)
        print ("Name:", area.spaces.active.camera.name)
```

Console Output (object reference and object name per viewport):

```
Object reference: <bpy_struct, Object("Camera") at 0x7fb1518c7008>
Name: Camera

Object reference: <bpy_struct, Object("Camera2") at 0x7fb1518c7008>
Name: Camera2

...
```